# How can I compare queried data with input data in excel, and then use that comparison in a conditional formatting rule?

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, excel-external-data

My company does packaging services, and as such our orders are put together by our CSR's and sent out to the warehouse. We have a check in place so that nothing falls through the cracks, but it requires someone to physically print a report and then locate everything in the dispatch office.

Essentially, I need to compare a column of queried data to a column of input data in a different tab, and then using a rule, highlight all cells in the rows on the queried tab where the input data column contains the queried cell.

The method I am working on now is an excel sheet that imports this information onto sheet 'Data', and then the CSR's will input their order numbers on sheet 'Input'.

On sheet 'Input' I have three columns: columns A for raw input, columns `B` which contains the formula `=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($C2,$A$2:$A$300,1,FALSE)))`, and columns `C`, which contains the formula `='Data'!$B2` (`B` is the column with the data I need).

Then, I compare `C` to `A` using columns `B`, and then my rule on sheet 'Data' is `='Input'!$B2=TRUE`

The issue is that 'A' and 'C' aren't recognized as equal when they should be. However, when I go to sheet 'Data' and double click the cell so that I can edit it, and then press enter, 'A' does recognize 'C', and 'B' becomes TRUE, and the rule applies formatting to the related rows. What is happening here, and how can I get 'A' to recognize 'C' automatically?

Comment: Sounds like you're dealing with numbers and text-that-looks-like-numbers perhaps. What is an example of data in C and A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience this may be the workaround:
If double-clicking on the cell "triggers" excel to reformat the value in the cell, then you can quickly force a column to reformat itself by using the "Text to Columns" function under the Data tab. Try highlighting the column on the 'data' sheet that is reformatting after you double-click. Once highlighted go to Data->Text to Columns->Make sure delimited is selected->then press "finish".

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! It works perfectly! However, this data is refreshed twice per day -- is there a way to automatically set these cells to delimited, rather than manually doing it? Note that rows are constantly added and removed from the 'Data' sheet. If not, that's fine, and thank you for your time and your helpful answer :)

Comment: I run in to this issue when I use the "Get Data" function in excel to link to an MS Access query. I have a text field of skus in my query, some of which are just numbers. When I type in those skus in excel, excel treats it as a number. Therefore, if I lookup this sku in my query, it will not come back as a match because the lookup function is looking for a number and only text values are present. From now on, I make sure new skus are alpha-numeric so that excel does not automatically treat them as numbers. Unfortunately, I am not sure another way to address this issue.